# Serverless geospatial data type conversion (similar to ogr2ogr)

Tags: ogr2ogr, google-earth-engine, cloud-gis

Is it possible to run ogr2ogr or Python/Fiona in a serverless environment where each feature gets processed in parallel and where you don't have to specify the properties of a virtual machine upfront?

I'm looking for a tool that can convert a variety of geospatial data types to something cloud GIS solutions such as AWS Athena, Google Biqguery and EarthEngine (in the future, current upload types are very limited) can work with.

An example I can think of is leveraging the power of [Apache Beam](https://beam.apache.org/) but I have not seen any I/O connector capable of reading geospatial data types and create parallel tasks.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the input and output? I'm not completely clear reading your question: Is the input a spatial database and you want to perform operations on each feature stored in there in parallel or do you want to perform tasks on a number of vector files, i.e. batch processing of files with serverless architecture - such as converting user uploaded content?

Comment: The latter: My use case is primarily ingesting a multitude of geospatial data types into these cloud services, performing some simple tasks during the process that cleans up the geometries, fixes issues (crossing 0180 meridian) etc.

Comment: So you are looking at an ETL pipeline that could be constructed, i.e. on AWS, of the type: S3 bucket -> start process on new file -> process -> push to other service or bucket. Right? That's certainly doable with the likes of [geolambda](https://github.com/developmentseed/geolambda). The only issue I see is how do you determine your clean-up steps? If you have those formalized as a script the rest can be constructed relatively easy with queue processing - be it with AWS, Hadoop, Kubernetes or Beam.

Answer (score 1):

This is an addon for Apache Beam that can load and process GIS data on Google Dataflow: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataflow-geobeam.

It includes I/O connectors for GeoTiff, Shapefiles, and Geodatabases.